# Text file with different data types into structure arrays

Tags: c, arrays, structure, file-processing

I have to parse a text file with 3 different data types. I want it to be saved in a structure array with three members. My text file look like this:

```
>A B 45.78965
>A C 35.46731
>B C 46.78695
```

I have written a code and when I run it at the terminal, it only showed a blinking underscore then after a while the program stopped. What should I do?

```
 #include"stdio.h"
                #include"string.h"
                struct gra{
                    char from;
                    char to;
                    double w;
                };
            int main(){
                FILE* fp;
            fp=fopen("graph.txt","r");  
            int i=0;
                while(!feof(fp)) {
                fscanf(fp,"%[^\t]",&graph[i].from,&graph[i].to,&graph[i].w);
                i++;
             } fclose(fp);}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct code.  Have you missed a declaration for `graph`?

Comment: A few points: First please format your code properly. Then please show a *complete* program, the one you have in your question is incomplete (e.g. what is `graph`?). And lastly, don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect, because the end-of-file flag is not set until *after* you try to read beyond the end of the file.

Comment: @Aq Toh : Why are you asking same question twice?